# Custom error page for 404 on images

Tags: servlets, custom-error-pages

I'm running a java web application, which currently has a custom error.xhtml defined in the web.xml for all 404 (not founds):

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Though, I want this to be simpler/different for images. In fact, it would be handy if I could inspec the request headers before deciding what to send back to the client for the 404.

Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: you could map the error location onto a servlet and then have the servlet decide what to send back

Answer (score 0):

Don't use static html resource then.

Map a servlet/jsp to the error code, and in the servlet check if the request was made for a image or script, etc... and make correct decision/action to response vary results.

example:

```
//servlet get, post, etc...
doGet(request,response){
   if(<<request was made for a *.jpg, *.png or image type?>>){
       //get request dispacther and forward it to a 404 image...
   }
}
```